# Error:No suitable method found for showImage(IplImage)

Tags: javacv

I am working on JavaCV, I created JFrame to show image upon action(clicking of button). But I am facing the above error of no suitable method.
It says argument mismatch; IplImage cannot be converted to image and Frame. Here is the snippet of code in which i am facing error:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        final opencv_core.IplImage image= cvLoadImage("D:\\Wallpapers\funny_download");
        final CanvasFrame canvas= new CanvasFrame("Demo");
       canvas.showImage(image);
       canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    }
```

The error shown is:

```
error: no suitable method found for showImage(IplImage)
   canvas.showImage(image);
method CanvasFrame.showImage(Frame) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; IplImage cannot be converted to Frame)
method CanvasFrame.showImage(Image) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; IplImage cannot be converted to Image)
```

please issue a solution, since I am working on a project.

Answer (score 1):

image is of type LblImage and showImage(args) needs a type Frame/Image as argument to work. You need to convert it to that type by using OpenCVFrameConverter.

Add (or replace) these two lines to your code and your program will work fine. Was having same problem for some hours too before getting my way around it.

```
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter=new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
    canvas.showImage(converter.convert(image));
```

Remember to import OpenCVFrameConverter library